# Qt Creator 4.7.0 failed to create a new project

Tags: qt-creator

As a new Qt learner, I have installed Qt Creator (4.7.0) on my iMac (macOS High Sierra 10.13.5). When I was trying to create a new project (Qt Quick Application - Empty), it failed with a popup as below.

[image]

I searched through the local path and found out that instead of "~/Qt/***Qt Creator.app***/Contents/..." the wizard was looking for, the actual path should be "~/Qt/***Qt Creator 4.7.0-rc1***/Contents/...". I believe there must be a configuration somewhere indicating the correct installation path but don't know where and how. Asking for help. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a work-around by adding an alias "Qt Creator" for "Qt Creator 4.7.0-rc1" but it seems awkward. Still waiting to see if there is any elegant solution.